# Exception in multipart/form-data web service on GlassFish OSE 3.1.2.2 (build 5)

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3

After updating from GlassFish OSE 3.1 (build 43) to GlassFish OSE 3.1.2.2 (build 5) multipart/form-data web services doesn't work any more. There is a `NullPointerException` caused in `com.sun.jersey.moxy.MoxyMessageBodyWorker.typeIsKnown` (see stack trace below for details). I've seen there was a problem with multipart/form-data requests in [3.1.2](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18444) but this should have been fixed in 3.1.2.2.

The web service's method signature is defined as follows:

```
@POST
@Path("/uploadphoto")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response uploadPhoto(@FormDataParam("photo") InputStream assetIs,
        @FormDataParam("photo") FormDataContentDisposition assetDisposition,
        @FormDataParam("width") Integer width,
        @FormDataParam("height") Integer height)
```

The following exception is thrown if the web service gets called. If the two additional parameters width and height are omitted the exception does NOT occur.

```
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: Exception obtaining parameters
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:54)
at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.FormDataMultiPartDispatchProvider$FormDataInjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(FormDataMultiPartDispatchProvider.java:125)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:203)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.jersey.moxy.MoxyMessageBodyWorker.typeIsKnown(MoxyMessageBodyWorker.java:110)
at com.sun.jersey.moxy.MoxyMessageBodyWorker.isReadable(MoxyMessageBodyWorker.java:133)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory._getMessageBodyReader(MessageBodyFactory.java:345)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory._getMessageBodyReader(MessageBodyFactory.java:315)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.getMessageBodyReader(MessageBodyFactory.java:298)
at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.FormDataMultiPartDispatchProvider$FormDataMultiPartParamInjectable.getValue(FormDataMultiPartDispatchProvider.java:297)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:46)
```

Is this a bug or do you have any hints how to solve this issue?

Thanks for your insights,
  Rene

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm hitting the same